# Matlab/Simulink - Dymola Interface. Dymolablock out of Date

Tags: matlab, simulink, dymola, s-function

I'm trying to create a compound model of Matlab and Dymola.
Therefore I followed this tutorial:
[Claytex tutorial](http://www.claytex.com/dymola-simulink-interface/)

Instead of the DrivenPendulum model, I made a simple model myself.
I can translate the model in Dymola just fine, and the Compilation of the Dymola model in Matlab works like in the tutorial, too.
But as soon as I try to simulate in Simulink I receive the following error message:

> Error evaluating 'InitFcn' callback of SubSystem block (mask) 'test/DymolaBlock/compmodel'. Block test/DymolaBlock is not up to date. Please recompile it!

Recompiling obviously doesn't work, I get this message again and again.

I'm using Dymola 2014 FD01 and Matlab 2010b with Visual Studio 2008 C++ Compiler.
Unfortunately I can't update Matlab at the moment as I'm working on an university computer, even though I assume this is the cause of the problem.

But maybe someone of you has an idea or even encountered this problem already?

Thanks in advance!